# Does cypress support multiple check if condition?

Tags: cypress

I have the following code in cypress:

```
    for(let i = 0; i < lengthOfRow; i++){
        if (
            Cypress.$(':nth-child(1) > :nth-child(6) > .index_textBlock_20DCh').eq(0).text().length == 0 &&
            Cypress.$(':nth-child(1) > :nth-child(7) > .index_textBlock_20DCh').eq(1).text().length == 0 &&
            Cypress.$(':nth-child(1) > :nth-child(8) > .index_textBlock_20DCh').eq(2).text().length == 0
          ) {
            //Do Something
            cy.get('tbody > :nth-child(1) > :nth-child(6)').click()
          } else if (
            Cypress.$(':nth-child(2) > :nth-child(6) > .index_textBlock_20DCh').eq(0).text().length == 0 &&
            Cypress.$(':nth-child(2) > :nth-child(7) > .index_textBlock_20DCh').eq(1).text().length == 0 &&
            Cypress.$(':nth-child(2) > :nth-child(8) > .index_textBlock_20DCh').eq(2).text().length == 0
          ){
            //Do Something
            cy.get('tbody > :nth-child(2) > :nth-child(6)').click() }
//another more conditions
```

Here I am checking blocks to be empty (otherwise go to elseIf), but it fail already at first check (error: should be empty, but found something). So my question whats wrong with this code and does cypress support multiple check using &&?

HTML:

```
<tr class = ="index_tr_2P">
<td class="index___td_halign_left_woynx index___td_1fTgv index__with-details_1OZkV index_tdHovered_1ZOPR index__has-background_1ZgcC"><div class="index_textBlock_20DCh">AnyText</div></td>
<td class="index___td_halign_left_woynx index___td_1fTgv index__with-details_1OZkV index_tdHovered_1ZOPR index__has-background_1ZgcC"><div class="index_textBlock_20DCh">SomeText</div></td>
<td class="index___td_halign_left_woynx index___td_1fTgv index__with-details_1OZkV index_tdHovered_1ZOPR index__has-background_1ZgcC"><div class="index_textBlock_20DCh">MoreTextHere</div></td>
</tr>

<tr class = ="index_tr_2P">
    <td class="index___td_halign_left_woynx index___td_1fTgv index__with-details_1OZkV index_tdHovered_1ZOPR index__has-background_1ZgcC"><div class="index_textBlock_20DCh">AnyText2</div></td>
    <td class="index___td_halign_left_woynx index___td_1fTgv index__with-details_1OZkV index_tdHovered_1ZOPR index__has-background_1ZgcC"><div class="index_textBlock_20DCh">SomeText2</div></td>
    <td class="index___td_halign_left_woynx index___td_1fTgv index__with-details_1OZkV index_tdHovered_1ZOPR index__has-background_1ZgcC"><div class="index_textBlock_20DCh">MoreTextHere2</div></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Please add your html containing these three elements that you are checking.

Comment: @AlapanDas added

Comment: So if the text is empty for all the three `td` elements then if condition should be executed otherwise else condition?

Comment: Yes, exactly. All three is empty at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of `nth:child()` and `eq()` making it hard to keep track of positions. Using `<tr>` and `<td>` selectors is a bit clearer.

This is how I'd approach it

```js
cy.get('tr').each(($tr, rowIndex) => {    // look at each row individually

  cy.wrap($tr)
    .find('td')                           // all cols inside this row
    .invoke('slice', 5, 8)                // filter to last 3 cols only
    .invoke('text')                       // get all the text in one lump
    .then(text => {
      if (text.trim() === '') {           // after trim(), is all text empty?
        console.log(`Row ${rowIndex+1} has three empty cols`) 
        cy.wrap($tr).find('td').eq(5).click()  // click the 6th col
      }
    })
})
```

**Assumptions**

- the three cols you want to test are on every row
- clicking the 6th col does not remove any rows

If the `click()` makes changes to the DOM, you can't use `cy.get('tr').each(...`

Comment: If I'm right this code check first row with columns. But how can I go to next row then?  Do I need to create loop?  Sayin I have 10 such rows

Comment: The Cypress `.each()` command is equivalent to `for(...)`. The only thing that can be a problem is if the `.click()` changes the rows. If you get a "Detached from DOM" error, let me know.

Comment: Getting error: 
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: td, but never found it. Queried from element: <tr>

Comment: It sounds like the table hasn't completed loading. Try with `cy.get('tr:has(td)').each(...`.

Comment: Now getting this error when click(): Timed out retrying after 4050ms: cy.click() failed because this element:

<td class="index___td_halign_left_woynx index___td_1fTgv index__with-details_1OZkV index_tdHovered_1ZOPR index__has-background_1ZgcC">...</td>

is being covered by another element:

<div class="slide_heading_2t5JS">Feedback on...</div>

Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking.

Comment: How can I resolve this?

Comment: "Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking" - starting with `click({force: true})` seems to be something to try, but this is another problem It looks like you've resolved the multiple condition issue.

Comment: Can you have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69604465/how-to-go-page-by-page-in-cypress

Answer (score 1):

Cypress is taking each "should" as an assertion so if any of those commands inside your "if" fail, your test will fail.
If this is your desired behavior then you should let each of them separately like this:

```
cy.get('body').then((body) => {
  cy.get(':nth-child(1) > :nth-child(6) > .index_textBlock_20DCh').should('be.empty')
cy.get(':nth-child(1) > :nth-child(7) > .index_textBlock_20DCh').should('be.empty')
cy.get(':nth-child(1) > :nth-child(8) > .index_textBlock_20DCh').should('be.empty')
cy.get('tbody > :nth-child(1) > :nth-child(6)').click()

//here continue with whatever was in your "else" without writing else
```

Cypress will execute each cy.get after the previous condition is true or fail.

Now for the "if" to work what you need is to access what your command yields. Only there you'll be able to do some comparison

So if you do this:

```
cy.get(':nth-child(1) > :nth-child(6) > .index_textBlock_20DCh').then((actualValue) => {
if(actualValue === ""){
} else {
}
})
```

That would work

Here's cypress documentation related to variables. The aliases part might help too for your multiple conditions if statement

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases

Comment: I need to check if the td have text inside.  So there are 3 blocks and I need all of them not to have text in the same time and then click to any of this block. I need those commands inside my if to be true

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```js
if (
  Cypress.$('td div.index_textBlock_20DCh').eq(0).is(':empty') &&
  Cypress.$('td div.index_textBlock_20DCh').eq(1).is(':empty') &&
  Cypress.$('td div.index_textBlock_20DCh').eq(2).is(':empty')
) {
  //Do Something
} else {
  //Do Something
}
```

You can also extract the text and check that the text length is 0. something like:

```js
if (
  Cypress.$('td div.index_textBlock_20DCh').eq(0).text().length == 0 &&
  Cypress.$('td div.index_textBlock_20DCh').eq(1).text().length == 0 &&
  Cypress.$('td div.index_textBlock_20DCh').eq(2).text().length == 0
) {
  //Do Something
} else {
  //Do Something
}
```

Using `each()`

```js
var countWithoutText = 0
cy.get('td div.index_textBlock_20DCh')
  .each((ele, lis) => {
    if (ele.text().length == 0) {
      countWithoutText++
    }
  })
  .then((lis) => {
    if (lis == countWithoutText) {
      //Do something all elements are empty
    } else {
      //Do something when all elements are not empty
    }
  })
```

Comment: But what if Ihave several rows of such elements? And they have equal td div.index_textBlock_20DCh. I need to go further and check them with cindition as well. Edited html

Comment: You can add an `each()` which will check one element per iteration.

Comment: Can you give example of using with each please?

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: But again it gets all td div.index_textBlock_20DCh at the same time

Comment: With each. It will get one element at a time and if there is no text it will increment the countWithoutText variable. Check the locator, may be just use `div.index_textBlock_20DCh`. Also I have changed the type of `countWithoutText` from const to var.

Comment: Edited my cypress code. It has selectors that is changing by 1 each row. Can you give example of each with it?